# $n \choose m$ as number of bijections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binomial-coefficients

I saw that my former question came from a certain exercise so I'll just write it down here:

It's to proof that the number of $m$-element subsets in an $n$-element set is $n \choose m$. A hint is given: Let $M \subset N$ be an $m$-element subset in the $n$-element set $N$. Show that the number of Bijections $f:\{1,...,n\}\to N$ such that $f(\{1,...,m\} = M$ is $m!(n-m)!$ and use Theorem XY.

Theorem XY says that the number of permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$ is $n!$.

My question: How does the hint help?

Answer (score 1):

You are double counting bijections.  For example, the identity bijection fixes all the subsets of size $M$, so is counted $n \choose m$ times here.

Added for the new question: You can think of lining up all the $n$ elements with the selected $m$ elements first in some order and the remaining $n-m$ later.  Theorem XY says this can be done in $m!(n-m)!$ ways.  Now it is fair to say there are $n!$ orders for all $n$ elements, so there are $\frac {n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ ways to select the first $m$ elements

Comment: Thanks, I took out my proposal and put it more generally.

Comment: I don't think there is any intuition for putting them together.  It is true they multiply to get $n!$, but I view that as an "accident"

Comment: Now I saw the original exercise and just posted it.